# What is the point of having an appsettings.json file in my Azure Function app?

Tags: azure-functions

I have seem examples online of developers using an appsettings.json file and injecting it like this in Program.cs

```
config.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);
```

My question is **why**? What is the benefit and purpose to doing this, when we already have host.json which seems to serve an identical purpose?
I am just confused on what functionality this has over host.json.I am using .NET 8 v4 Isolated Functions if that matters.

Answer (score 0):

It's just bad form and you should not do it. These developers you see examples from seem to be used to developing web applications in MVC and the like, where the appsettings file is the central place to put the "settings" of an app.

The thing is. Azure functions have a very specific place to put these settings. Locally you can put it in local.settings.json. This file is only used on you local machine for debugging. It's ignored for git and not pushed to the cloud.

When deploying to a function app in the azure cloud, you can set these settings for the production environment through the azure portal for azure functions in the settings tab.

The limitation with doing it this way is that the azure function settings only supports name value pairs. No complex objects and such. A feature many developeres like from the appsettings way of doing things. However! To change this appsettings file you have to redeploy a function. If you use the settings stuff in the azure portal you don't have to do that and you can have slot specific settings and such. In my opinion (others may disagree) changing configuration should never require redeploying something.

for more reading:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal

Answer (score -1):

@user3010678

So, using appsettings.json in your Azure Functions app is like having a dedicated spot for all your application-specific settings. It's a comon practice in .NET to keep infra related stuff in host.json and application-specific configurations in appsettings.json.

Here is a sample snipp tp demonstrate

```html
// Program.cs

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add configuration from appsettings.json
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true);

// Access configuration settings
var mySetting = builder.Configuration["MySetting"];

// Now, you can use 'mySetting' in your app
// ...

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the application
// ...

app.Run();
```

add the app.jspn like this

```html
// appsettings.json

{
  "MySetting": "SomeValue",
  "AnotherSetting": {
    "SubSetting": "SubValue"
  }
}
```

If you can see above you can easily store your app-specific settings in appsettings.json and retrieve them in your code.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But I still dont understand I guess, why not put these values in host.json or local.settings.json? Can you explain more the difference between "Infrastructure" settings and "application" settings? Is logging considered application or infrastructure?

Comment: This is not the azure function way of doing things. Use the host.json and local.settings.json setup and configure deployed settings in the azure functions portal pag. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal